# Using Database in Fragment

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-fragments

I'm trying to make a basic lyric writing app that will allow you to save, edit, and store lyrics - however halfway through the project i've decided that I wanted to use different tabs, so that the user can click on another tab while editing a lyric and etc features. I have a lot of incorrect code, and I know it is because I switched to a class that extends Fragment....I'm just having a tough time reworking everything. Could someone please tell me if there are just a few small tweaks I can make? And any advice on what those tweaks may be? Thanks for any and all help!! Here's my code:

```
public class LyricListFragment extends Fragment {

private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;
private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
private LyricsDbAdapter mDbHelper;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_lyriclist);
    mDbHelper = new LyricsDbAdapter(getActivity());
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_lyriclist, container, false);
    return view;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
    return true;
}

private void fillData() {
    Cursor LyricsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllLyrics();
    startManagingCursor(LyricsCursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{LyricsDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

    SimpleCursorAdapter lyrics = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.lyrics_row, LyricsCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(lyrics);
}

public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case INSERT_ID:
            createLyric();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case DELETE_ID:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            mDbHelper.deleteLyric(info.id);
            fillData();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private void createLyric() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), LyricEditorFragment.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), LyricEditorFragment.class);
    i.putExtra(LyricsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    fillData();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TabHost` inside a `Fragment` just fine. A `TabActivity` is not necessary to host the tabs. `TabActivity` only provides some functionality that you can also add to a `Fragment` yourself. Check out the [TabHost](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/761642-android-app-development-for-beginners-navigation-with-tabs) docs, especially the section about [addTab()](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/761642-android-app-development-for-beginners-navigation-with-tabs).

You can also check the [Android Fragements with Tabs](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/761642-android-app-development-for-beginners-navigation-with-tabs) and [Android Tabs with ListFragments](http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbar-tab-listfragment-in-android.html)